# Run PHP code only when user clicks

Tags: php, facebook

I have a PHP file in which I have this code:

```
$descText = $_POST["fname"];
$attachement = array('access_token'=>$fbme['access_token'], 'message' => $descText, 'source' => '@'.realpath($tempFile) );
//$attachement = array('access_token'=>$fbme['access_token'], 'source' => '@'.realpath($tempFile) );
$fb_photo = $facebook->api('me/photos','POST',$attachement);

$FQLQuery = 'SELECT object_id, pid, src_big, link FROM photo WHERE object_id = '.$fb_photo['id'];
$FQLResult = $facebook->api(array( 'method' => 'fql.query', 'query' => $FQLQuery, 'access_token'=>$fbme['access_token'] ));
$targetPhoto = $FQLResult[0];
echo '<center><h1>Image created.</h1><br/><img src="'.$targetPhoto['src_big'].'"/></center><br/>';
```

How can I run this only when a user clicks on a button or link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a form HTML tag. This is just an example:

```
<form method="post" action="yourphpfile.php">
    <input type="text" name="fname" value="your first name?" />
    <input type="submit" value="run" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't attach PHP code to a HTML input button, only JavaScript.

If you need to have the code written in PHP then you will either have to link directly to the script, which will display a page with your photo on it (Assuming the code is valid), or more likely what you want is to USE AJAX to include it dynamically in an existing page.

Basically something like this would work in JQuery:

```
<input type="button" onclick="$.load('/link/to/script.php', $('#where_to_put_the_image'));" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a file and then link to that file. Simple.

Or do you want to run it asynchronously on the page? In which case, you'll need to do it using [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

Answer (score 0):

As with triggering *any* PHP script or function, send a request to the page that contains it, either by a link, a form post, or an Ajax request.